# Possible bug in retagging

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

I retagged [loading data from a flat file to table using informatica, having both english and foreign language characters like chinese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741044/loading-data-from-a-flat-file-to-table-using-informatica-having-both-english-and) using the "edit tags" link (visible to 10K users) from "**language** characters informatica **foreign**" to "informatica **foreign-language**."

When I look at the question it still shows the old tags, but when I edit the tags or the question I see the new tags.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Same problem with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878501

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran a process yesterday that **re-sorted all tags from left to right in order of frequency**. In other words, the most frequently used tag is on the left and the least is on the right.

(and on meta and stackapps, required and mod tags sort all the way to the left)

This only changed the current version, it did not change the post history.

I'll be checking in a change later which enforces this per-edit.

Comment: @Jeff: They are sorted in order of frequency, but these are the **old tags**, my edit is lost (I see the new tags when I edit the question, but the old tags when I view it). Did you use some cached tags to change the order?

Comment: @peter you just got very unlucky, as the retagger hit the post while you were editing. history was not touched as that would have been extremely expensive.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks. It worked for some questions, but I don't seem to be able to restore my edited tags for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018471. Editing again does not change the tags. I'm trying to get rid of the `foreign` tag which does not add any value but has been used to tag questions `foreign key` instead of `foreign-key` (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50665/)

Comment: @peter the code is seeing "no tags changed" so rejecting the edit. I added a bogus tag, then removed it.

Comment: I don't think sorting tags by popularity order is necessarily a good thing, they should be in order of importance which is best decided by the OP.

Comment: i agree, this is a horrible change.  tags' relative positions can carry meaning as well, and this completely destroys that.  i can see doing this for the required tags on Meta (and other sites that have them), but otherwise it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue.

Also, if you look at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1741044/revisions) you can clearly see that you retagged the question.