# Are the tags shown in a particular order?

Tags: support, tags, questions

I noticed that, sometimes, the tags I add to a question are not shown in the same order I wrote them, when the question is saved.
Are they shown in a particular order? If they are, in which order they are shown?

Comment: probably by popularity, and I think this is dup.

Comment: Tags are indeed ordered by popularity as of their most recent revision. Just confirming that whilst the search goes on. [This is a related example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77808/does-it-matter-the-order-you-tag-your-question), but not quite the dupe one might be seeking.

Comment: And here is the ["I tagged a question in one order but it came out differently!"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50794/possible-bug-in-retagging/50819#50819) report, with the accompanying answer that we've echoed in the comments. ♪ That said, this *is* a support question rather than a bug report, even though it's asking about the same phenomenon... so...

Comment: @GraceNote The question you link in your last comment is about a question showing the old tags after a user edited them; it's not about the order the tags are shown, but which tags are shown.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, they are sorted by the following rules:

- in order of tag popularity from left to right
- on meta and stackapps sites, the required/mod tags take precedence

[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50794/possible-bug-in-retagging/50819#50819)

If you disagree with this and think you should be able to order it, there is a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51157/do-not-order-tags-on-questions-based-popularity-and-keep-them-in-order-specified) to allow the asker to specify the order.

Comment: The order the tags are shown is fine with me. I was trying to understand why sometimes they are ordered differently from the order I wrote them, and sometimes not. Your answer makes that clear. Thank you.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yeah, I just found the proposal while searching for the source information and thought it'd be prudent to include just in case :)

Comment: I appreciated you included that link too; I will follow that feature report. `:-)`