# Make the go tag a top-level language tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are the tags shown in a particular order?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87508/are-the-tags-shown-in-a-particular-order)

I just noticed that for the question:

[Making sense of some bit magic in the Go standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512021/making-sense-of-some-bit-magic-in-the-go-standard-library)

[go](/questions/tagged/go) is not the chosen to be displayed in the title. [colors](/questions/tagged/colors) was selected.

It is displayed as: `colors - QUESTION-TEXT`
but it should be `go - QUESTION-TEXT`

I assume, that the go tag has to be defined by someone as a special top-level tag?

[go](/questions/tagged/go) is the tag for [googles go language](http://www.golang.org).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags are ordered by frequency, and apparently [colors](/questions/tagged/colors) is beating out [go](/questions/tagged/go).