# Tag order by frequency

Tags: support, tags, sorting

Tags in questions are ordered by frequency accourding to [that post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50819/172011).

I noticed [a question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569931/get-properties-of-vb-element) does not follow that order (if frequency is equal to the number of followers of a tag).

If I am wrong: How to see the frequency of a tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of followers/subscribers is something different than the number of times the tag is used on a question. The latter is what determines the order of the tags.

The frequency of usage of the tags on that question is shown in the right sidebar:

[image]