# In which order the tags are placed in the questions?

Tags: support, tags, questions, sorting

I often saw the questions with tags arranged in order by the no. of posts per tag. ie, the tags with higher number of questions will be placed first.

Tag [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) having more questions than [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) and [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c).

But in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616760/objective-c-json-dictionary-to-json) question, iOS tag is placed after the other two tags.

While sorting the questions below the [newest tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios?sort=newest&pageSize=50), the tags are placed by the order by which I stated above. But, If I switch to the [votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios?sort=votes&pageSize=50) tab, the tags are placed differently.

EDIT:

As it is mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87527/186599), the tags are placed based on their popularity, why is it not updated to the current popularity of the tag?

Comment: maybe back then when the question was asked (2011) the logic was similar but iphone had been tagged more times than ios? just a wild guess

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. They're just shown in the order they're added to the post, surely? Like with your meta post here - you wrote `questions` before you wrote `sorting` so they're in that order.

Comment: @JonW afaik there is indeed a sorting order depending on the number of uses of the tag.

Comment: @Stijn How does that duplicate explain the sorting in this particular case?

Comment: @Bart: Hmm, can't say I've ever noticed myself. But I guess I may just not have been paying enough attention if that's the case!

Comment: @Bart perhaps the answer to that question is outdated, but this one is still a duplicate. The answer should either be edited appropriately or a new answer should be posted.

Comment: @Stijn, edited to not to  be a duplicate.

Comment: @Bart: the sorting is created *at the time the question was posted*.

Comment: Emphasis or quote there @MartijnPieters?

Comment: If the sorting was updated every time someone merely *looked* at a question, the performance hit to the site would cripple it.

Comment: @Bart: emphasis. The tags field is denormalized in the table; each post row has a tags text field that contains the tags in the order they were sorted at the time of the last tag edit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, if I retag an old question now, will it be sorted by the current tag popularity?

Comment: @Azik: Yes, it will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags are sorted by popularity *at the time of the last tag edit*.

In other words, the ordering is cached; there is little point in reordering it each time a post is loaded from the database.

If you were to edit the tags on that post now, the tags would be resorted.

Comment: Here's a [source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50794/possible-bug-in-retagging/50819#50819) confirming this answer. (It's also mentioned in the *possible duplicate*)