# Why are some user cards white?

Tags: support, user-card

I noticed that some users have a white user card, and their name in the comments is also surrounded by a white box. (I'm using dark mode, otherwise they're blue) Why is this?

[image]

(screenshot taken from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50794/295232))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because they are the author of the question. If you know that, it may help providing context for comments. It's bluish white (#dce9f6) because you have dark mode enabled (through a browser extension or something similar); normally, the card is more blue, like this:

[image]

Mine is not; it's white/transparent, just like the page background.

If you inspect the HTML, you will see that the corresponding element has the `owner` class, which is responsible for the special background color. The browser extension transforms it into something more white.

Comment: Wait, Meta has dark mode as well?

Comment: @nobody no. The screenshot in the question is from Stack Overflow.

Comment: Uh, AFAIKT, it is [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50794/906149) which is on meta.

Comment: @nobody hang on, you're right. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: I use a dark mode browser extension

Comment: @Tuor: Perhaps [add](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/375301/edit) that information to the question? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.)

Comment: @this done, though this is superfluous and redundant, because the question is closed